# I can't understand what "terminal" is

Tags: windows, macos, github, terminal, difference

I'm using Microsoft, the instructor is teaching on his Mac. On Git Hub he copied the link and put it on      "TERMINAL" I don't understand what it was, so I couldn't find that one to paste my link.

Comment: Q: Why don't you ask the instructor?  I presume that's what he/she is there for!!!  A MacOS [terminal](https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/welcome/mac) is just a command line interface.  The equivalent on Windows is "cmd.exe".  The "gotcha" is that commands you'd type in a "terminal" on MacOS are completely *different* from commands on DOS/Windows.  For example, "del" (DOS/Windows) vs. "rm" (Linux/MacOS).  But definitely ask your instructor.  Make him/her work for their pay ;)

Comment: terminal usually means the command line interface (CLI)where you can interact with the computer by typing commands.?

Answer (score 1):

The terminal is the mac equivalent to the command prompt on windows, if you want to access it just type cmd in your start menu.